# How to pass multiple host url's in the transport object for createTransport function in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Is it possible to configure multiple host value with their respective ports in transport object of `createTransport` function of nodemailer library.

Right now my code is:

```
var transport = {
host: "devint.test.com",
port: 22,
auth: {
    user: "test",
    pass: "test"
    }
}                   

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);
```

In above transport object, I have passed single host i.e. **devint.test.com** in **host property** of **transport** object. In my application, there are multiple email server, So I want to pass multiple host name and their port in the host and port property of transport object. Is there any way to do?

PS: For now forget about that reason for having multiple email server, its long story.

Comment: No, This link talks about multiple recipients, I am asking for multiple host. I want to send same maiil through multiple email server.

Comment: according to my knowledge we can't !!! but if we can then, I am also curious to get this answer. +1 :-)